# Knockout js foreach not bind anything

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

I have trouble with Knockout js, I tried KO3.2 and 2.3 not help.

```
<div data-bind='template: { foreach: otherLanguages, beforeRemove: hideElement, afterAdd: showElement }'>
     <span data-bind='text: name'> </span>
</div>
```

databinding not work, but in chrome tool I see

```
" otherLanguages": Array[1]
    0: Object
        name: "C#"
```

Than I try sample from official web

```
KO test
    <ul data-bind="foreach: ['cats', 'dogs', 'fish']">
        <li>The value is <span data-bind="text: $data"></span></li>
    </ul>
```

And I get this output:

```
KO test
    The value is
```

I use ASP.NET MVC 5, I try join KO via bundles, CDN, than

```
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
```

not work. I try many browser.

Where can be problem?

Comment: Where do you call `ko.applyBindings()`?

Comment: @nemesv I'm sorry for that, I did not mention
 
$(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new IndexViewModel());
    });

Comment: Is the *code itself* not working, or is the Knockout script not being loaded into the browser correctly?  Also, can you post enough of your Javascript code so that your problem can be replicated?

Comment: Or a jsfiddle version that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Add a code snippet to check your ViewModel. Is the icon near the insert image (a pen over a paper)